# Container image shows configuration vulnerability with openssh server package

Tags: ibm-cloud, openssh

One of my images in registry shows this configuration issue:

```
Security Practice

SSH server package, openssh-server of version (none):7.4p1-21.el7, found.

How to Resolve

checking if ssh server is installed
```

But I am not sure what exactly does this mean? We do install `7.4p1-21.el7` version. Does this suggest ot upgrade? The resolution is not very clear.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are seeing this issue in the report is because it is not a good practice to install SSH in containers.

However, if you do require SSH you can create an exemption for this check so that this issue will no longer be flagged against the image in the report.
You can either do this with the IBM Cloud Container Registry(cr) command line with the command

```
ibmcloud cr exemption-add --help
```

or through the UI by clicking on the action menu (three vertical dots) next to the configuration issue --> Create exemption.

For more information on setting exemption policy, check the documentation [here](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/va?topic=va-va_index#va_managing_policy)